# Implementing Strong and Causal Consistency in Java using Vert.x

Tags: java, database, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am trying to understand the concept of Strong and Causal consistency by implementing it in Multi-threaded Java. I have written the following code using the Vert.x framework. I am trying to implement the following:

**Strong Consistency**

1. Every PUT (write) request is atomic across all replicas.
2. At any point in time, only 1 PUT request per key can be performed on the datacenter instances.
3. A GET operation per key is to be blocked if a PUT operation for the same key is being processed.
4. The locking of datacenters is to be done at key level i.e. operations on multiple keys can run in parallel.

**Causal Consistency**

1. ALL PUT operations per key must be seen in all the datacenters in the same order.
2. At any point in time, different operations can be performed in different datacenters in parallel. That is, lock only one datacenter at a time for an operation per key.
3. A GET operation returns the value immediately without being blocked even if it is stale.

**API on the Vert.x server**

Here are the following GET and PUT operations that the Vert.x server will receive and must implement:

```
Vertx-DNS:8080/put?key=KEY&value=VALUE
```

This endpoint will receive the key, value pair that needs to be stored in the datacenter instances

```
Vertx-DNS:8080/get?key=KEY&loc=LOCATION
```

This endpoint will receive the key for which the value has to be returned by the Vertx server. The server has to return the value as the response to this request. The location value is 1 for datacenter1, 2 for datacenter2 and 3 datacenter3.

```
KeyValueLib.PUT(String datacenterDNS, String key, String value) throws IOException
```

This API method will put the value for the specified key in the specified datacenter instance.

```
KeyValueLib.GET(String datacenterDNS, String key) throws IOException
```

This API method returns the value for the specified key from the specified datacenter.

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.vertx.java.core.Handler;
import org.vertx.java.core.MultiMap;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServer;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.RouteMatcher;
import org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle;

public class Coordinator extends Verticle {

    //Default mode: Strongly consistent. Possible values are "strong" and "causal"
    private static String consistencyType = "strong";

    /**
     * TODO: Set the values of the following variables to the DNS names of your
     * three dataCenter instances
     */
    private static final String dataCenter1 = "ec2-52-2-18-9.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    private static final String dataCenter2 = "ec2-52-2-12-29.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
    private static final String dataCenter3 = "ec2-52-2-10-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com";

    @Override
    public void start() {
        //DO NOT MODIFY THIS
        KeyValueLib.dataCenters.put(dataCenter1, 1);
        KeyValueLib.dataCenters.put(dataCenter2, 2);
        KeyValueLib.dataCenters.put(dataCenter3, 3);
        final RouteMatcher routeMatcher = new RouteMatcher();
        final HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        server.setAcceptBacklog(32767);
        server.setUsePooledBuffers(true);
        server.setReceiveBufferSize(4 * 1024);

        routeMatcher.get("/put", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final HttpServerRequest req) {
                MultiMap map = req.params();
                final String key = map.get("key");
                final String value = map.get("value");
                //You may use the following timestamp for ordering requests
                final String timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() 
                                                                + TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getRawOffset()).toString();
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //TODO: Write code for PUT operation here.
                        //Each PUT operation is handled in a different thread.
                        //Use helper functions.
                        try{
                            switch(consistencyType) {
                            case "strong":
                                //Do 
                                break;
                            case "causal":
                                //Do
                                break;
                            default: continue;
                        }


                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
                req.response().end(); //Do not remove this
            }
        });

        routeMatcher.get("/get", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final HttpServerRequest req) {
                MultiMap map = req.params();
                final String key = map.get("key");
                final String loc = map.get("loc");
                //You may use the following timestamp for ordering requests
                final String timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() 
                                + TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getRawOffset()).toString();
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //TODO: Write code for GET operation here.
                                                //Each GET operation is handled in a different thread.
                                                //Highly recommended that you make use of helper functions.
                        req.response().end("0"); //Default response = 0
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

        routeMatcher.get("/consistency", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(final HttpServerRequest req) {
                                MultiMap map = req.params();
                                consistencyType = map.get("consistency");
                                req.response().end();
                        }
                });

        routeMatcher.noMatch(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final HttpServerRequest req) {
                req.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
                String response = "Not found.";
                req.response().putHeader("Content-Length",
                        String.valueOf(response.length()));
                req.response().end(response);
                req.response().close();
            }
        });
        server.requestHandler(routeMatcher);
        server.listen(8001);
    }
}
```

**KeyValueLib.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class KeyValueLib {
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> dataCenters = new HashMap();

    private static String URLHandler(String string) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String string2;
            URL uRL = new URL(string);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL
                    .openConnection();
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new IOException(httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((string2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(string2);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException var2_3) {
            var2_3.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void PUT(String string, String string2, String string3)
            throws IOException {
        String string4 = String.format("http://%s:8001/put?key=%s&value=%s",
                string, string2, string3);
        String string5 = KeyValueLib.URLHandler(string4);
        try {
            switch (dataCenters.get(string)) {
                case 1 : {
                    break;
                }
                case 2 : {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    break;
                }
                case 3 : {
                    Thread.sleep(800);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException var5_5) {
            // empty catch block
        }
        if (!string5.equals("stored")) {
            System.out.println("Some error happened");
        }
    }

    public static String GET(String string, String string2) throws IOException {
        String string3 = String.format("http://%s:8001/get?key=%s", string,
                string2);
        String string4 = KeyValueLib.URLHandler(string3);
        return string4;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me how to implement this?